# EntityFramework with UnitOfWork to Service pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following layers in my application.

1. Repository.Ef (this handle the context of ef)
2. Entities (here is all entities for ef)
3. Core (This layer handle all business and works like a wrapper
   between Ef <> Gui)
4. Gui (This is the User interface)

I have interface for most of the classes and use DI, but this version is compressed to only show the classes.

This is the UnitOfWork, that hold the DbContext in my Repository.Ef layer.

```
public class UnitOfWork : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
    {
        static UnitOfWork()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UnitOfWork>(null);
        }

        public UnitOfWork()
            : base("Name=SalesDb") 
        {
        }

        public IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : EntityBase
        {
            return new Repository<T>(Set<T>());
        }

        public void ApplyStateChanges()
        {
            foreach (var dbEntityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                var entityState = dbEntityEntry.Entity as EntityBase;
                if (entityState == null)
                    throw new InvalidCastException("All entites must implement the IObjectState interface, " +
                                                   "this interface must be implemented so each entites state can explicitely determined when updating graphs.");

                dbEntityEntry.State = StateHelper.ConvertState(entityState.State);
            }
        }

        #region DBSET

    // HERE IS ALL MY DBSETS

        #endregion

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            ApplyStateChanges();
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And this is my Repository (same layer as UnitOfWork)

```
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(DbSet<T> dbSet)
    {
        _dbSet = dbSet;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query()
    {
        var data = _dbSet.AsQueryable();
        return data;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        entity.State = ObjectState.Added;
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        entity.State = ObjectState.Deleted;
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        entity.State = ObjectState.Modified;
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
    }
}
```

Here is my Core layer (Business rules and the wrapper between GUI layer)
The following is my ServiceUnit.

```
  public class ServiceUnit
{
    internal readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public ServiceUnit()
    {
        unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    }

    public void Add<T>(T entity, int marketId, string username) where T : EntityBase
    {
        entity.MarketId = marketId;
        entity.ChUser = username;
        entity.ChTime = DateTime.Now;
        entity.Deleted = false;

        unitOfWork.Repository<T>().Add(entity);
        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update<T>(T entity, string username) where T : EntityBase
    {
        entity.ChUser = username;
        entity.ChTime = DateTime.Now;

        unitOfWork.Repository<T>().Update(entity);
        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Remove<T>(int id) where T : EntityBase
    {
        var entity = unitOfWork.Repository<T>().FindById(id);
        entity.Deleted = true;
        entity.ChTime = DateTime.Now;

        unitOfWork.Repository<T>().Update(entity);
        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(int? marketId = null, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : EntityBase
    {
        var data = unitOfWork.Repository<T>()
            .Find(predicate);

        if (marketId != null)
        {
            data = data
                .Where(t => t.MarketId == marketId);
        }

        return data;
    }

    public T FindById<T>(int id) where T : EntityBase
    {
        return unitOfWork.Repository<T>().FindById(id);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

And this is a Service class to handle all Contact functions

```
    public class ContactService
{
    private readonly ServiceUnit serviceUnit;

    private IRepository<Contact> contactRep
    {
        get { return serviceUnit.unitOfWork.Repository<Contact>(); }
    }

    private IRepository<ContactUserProfile> contactUserProfileRep
    {
        get { return serviceUnit.unitOfWork.Repository<ContactUserProfile>(); }
    }

    public ContactService(ServiceUnit serviceUnit)
    {
        this.serviceUnit = serviceUnit;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ContactUserProfile> GetContactsForUser(int marketId, int userId, int status)
    {
        return contactUserProfileRep
            .Query()
            .Where(u => u.Contact.MarketId == marketId)
            .Where(cup => cup.UserProfileId == userId)
            .Where(c => c.Deleted == false)
            .Where(c => c.Contact.Status == status)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Lets explain how i use all this code.
First of all, i dont want to have dependency for entity framework in my gui layer, and with this service wrapper (ServiceUnit) i dont have to reference entity framework.

Every page request create a ServiceUnit, and the ServiceUnit create a new UnitOfWork that hold whole the EntityFramework context.

For example, the contact page create a ServiceUnit and a ServiceContact and inject the Service unit, so i have the same context for the request.

Can this pattern cause any problem? Just want to se if i missed something importent here.

Comment: within your UnitOfWork implimentation nice to have dispose method to dispose the context

Comment: This would fit better at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq). StackOverflow is for _specific_ programming problems. (Things that go wrong or you can't get to work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the "ServiceUnit" class? Why not use the UnitOfWork directly in your services?

What I'd suggest is basically to have have four projects:

- Data Access Layer Project: EF DbContext, Repositories, UnitOfWork. References "Entities" project.
- Entities Project: EF entities (if you want to share the EF entities
  throughout the solution). Doesn't reference any other project.
- Service Layer Project: ContactService, etc. Each has the UnitOfWork
  injected into them. References "Data Access Layer" and "Entities" project.
- GUI Project: with your UI. References "Entities" and "Service Layer" project.

I think ServiceUnit is an unnecessary abstraction, and services can deal with UnitOfWork directly (unless I'm missing something).

By the way, I wouldn't recommend exposing IQueryable from your repositories (as someone suggested to me on another question). Once you expose it, the query is executed outside your repository and so you loose control over its execution (exception handling, etc.). If you search a bit you'll see there's some controversy over this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. All my pages is derived from a base page that use ServiceUnit for simple Create, Update, Read functions. And this page is generic, and this is why i need this extra wrapper.